# When should I make a UIView compared to a custom View Controller?

Tags: ios

I've been having arguments over this, what is the justification for making some sort of component a UIViewController as opposed to a view? Ive been under the assumption of 1 view controller per screen with the exception if you're using a navigation view controller or something similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a `UIViewController` class when you need a full blown view controller. You create a `UIView` when you are just creating some sort of "widget" that will get added to a parent view (such as a view controller's view).

Think of a view controller as a "screen". This view controller represents an entire screen. It's main view can have lots of subviews added to it. The controller is responsible for accessing data and coordinating events from the views and providing data to the views.

A button is view. A table is a view. An image is a view. But a view controller combines all of those views and connects them all together.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very much related to MVC pattern and how to separate controller and view parts. One viewcontroller for one screen does makes sense in general and I remember formerly it was suggested in apple guidelines, it is changed now but still works in most cases.

iOS view library is quite comprehensive and I usually don't find the need to create custom views but instead custom viewcontrollers. Because in an app following the MVC pattern viewcontroller is the middle man interacting with both views and data (model), your views should not directly connected to your model which limits its functionality in a great deal. Think of it this way look at the generic ios view library, your new class should reside with other controls such as uibutton, uiswitch, uitableview, if it does not  need to contain complex logic (doing computations, interacting with other views or objects) but it is enough to notify user's interaction to controller.

My typical usages of custom views are when I need a composition of uiviews (ie content slider in many webpages, 10 rating stars in movie pages in imdb) and need a different representation (ie represent some data in piechart or an improved progress bar etc) But otherwise almost always I go for the custom viewcontroller.